# System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, apache-axis

System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at

```
http://prodserver:8080/FxWebservice/services/FxRateFetcher.FxRateFetcherHttpSoap11Endpoint/
```

that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

-- I am calling this webservice hosted on server which use tomcat/axis2 for hosting.

Now when I open this link in browser

```
http://servername:8080/FxWebservice/services/FxRateFetcher?wsdl
```

it open correct but when I open any of SOAP links or even http links it does not open.

This cause exception in code.

On server it does work and show everything fine on axis2 webbased manager.

Also from axis2 services when I try to open EPR link it does not open.

May be any config or web xmls wrong?

Can someone please point what part is wrong in hosting this webservice?

Comment: Also on Server side: Tomcat have this error message The Endpoint Reference (EPR) for the operation not found is xxx and WSA Action = null